# Can Keras with Tensorflow backend be forced to use CPU or GPU at will?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have Keras installed with the Tensorflow backend and CUDA.  I'd like to sometimes on demand force Keras to use CPU.  Can this be done without say installing a separate CPU-only Tensorflow in a virtual environment?  If so how?  If the backend were Theano, the flags could be set, but I have not heard of Tensorflow flags accessible via Keras.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you want to force Keras to use CPU

### Way 1

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
```

before Keras / Tensorflow is imported.

### Way 2

Run your script as

```
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" ./your_keras_code.py
```

See also

1. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/152
2. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4613

Comment: Didn't work for me (Keras 2, Windows) - had to set `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'` as in an answer below

Comment: What issue is #152 referring to? A link would be nice.

Comment: I don't see any reference to `CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID` in issue #152

Comment: I am in a ipython3 terminal and I've set 
```import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
```,
now how do I "undo" this ? I would like Keras to use the GPU again.

Comment: @MartinThoma I mean without having to leave the ipython, I had many things run in it so I would like to set back to a "GPU enabled" environment. I tried deleting the keys in the os.environ dictionary, in vain.

Comment: I see. You will have to reload tensor flow / keras after changing the environment variables

Comment: As a note: I had to perform these lines **BEFORE** I declared my keras model. If you do it afterwards it will use the GPU by default

Answer (score 83):

This worked for me (win10), place before you import keras:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: With Win, forces TF to use CPU and ignore any GPU. Didn't have luck with 0 or blank, but -1 seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Worked on Win10 x64 for me. I also didn't have any luck win 0 or blank and only -1 worked.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu

Comment: I have two GPU s in my machine, setting the 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'  = 0/1 is referring to the physical ID of the available GPU's. Setting it to -1 uses CPU.

Comment: Is there also a way to force it to use GPU?

Answer (score 79):

A rather separable way of doing this is to use

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

num_cores = 4

if GPU:
    num_GPU = 1
    num_CPU = 1
if CPU:
    num_CPU = 1
    num_GPU = 0

config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=num_cores,
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=num_cores, 
                        allow_soft_placement=True,
                        device_count = {'CPU' : num_CPU,
                                        'GPU' : num_GPU}
                       )

session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
```

Here, with `booleans` `GPU` and `CPU`, we indicate whether we would like to run our code with the GPU or CPU by rigidly defining the number of GPUs and CPUs the Tensorflow session is allowed to access. The variables `num_GPU` and `num_CPU` define this value. `num_cores` then sets the number of CPU cores available for usage via `intra_op_parallelism_threads` and `inter_op_parallelism_threads`.

The `intra_op_parallelism_threads` variable dictates the number of threads a parallel operation in a single node in the computation graph is allowed to use (intra). While the `inter_ops_parallelism_threads` variable defines the number of threads accessible for parallel operations across the nodes of the computation graph (inter).

`allow_soft_placement` allows for operations to be run on the CPU if any of the following criterion are met:

1. there is no GPU implementation for the operation
2. there are no GPU devices known or registered
3. there is a need to co-locate with other inputs from the CPU

All of this is executed in the constructor of my class before any other operations, and is completely separable from any model or other code I use.

Note: This requires `tensorflow-gpu` and `cuda`/`cudnn` to be installed because the option is given to use a GPU.

Refs:

- [What do the options in ConfigProto like allow_soft_placement and log_device_placement mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873273/what-do-the-options-in-configproto-like-allow-soft-placement-and-log-device-plac)
- [Meaning of inter_op_parallelism_threads and intra_op_parallelism_threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233635/meaning-of-inter-op-parallelism-threads-and-intra-op-parallelism-threads)

Comment: This is a nice solution as just defining "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" causes CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE followed by a lot of diagnostics before continuing on to executing on the CPU. Though... both methods work!

Comment: This is the only consistent solution that works for me. Keep coming back to it.

Comment: Can you please explain what the other parameters mean? like `allow_soft_placement`, `intra_op_parallelism_threads`, `inter_op_parallelism_threads`

Comment: are the `inter`/`intra_op_parallelism_threads` refer to CPU or GPU operations?

Comment: @bluesummers They pertain to CPU parallelization

Comment: this one works. the accepted answer doesn't (for me)

Comment: If I want to force CPU here, will this ensure that no memory is allocated on the GPU? Because I need to run a separate model on the CPU because the GPU will be occupied in the same python context. I was  wondering whether to use a subprocess based on the first answer. But if this works, it will be alot easier to just fork and create a new session for the subprocess?

Comment: Why is `num_CPU` set to 1 and not the number of cores?

Answer (score 38):

Just import tensortflow and use keras, it's that easy.

```
import tensorflow as tf
# your code here
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=20, batch_size=128, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Comment: When I set the `tf.device('/cpu:0')`, I could still see memory being allocated to python later with `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Solve it or not ^_^?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me either, still uses gpu when I set it to use cpu

Comment: Should not be also model definition and compile executed under the same `with`?

Answer (score 30):

As per keras [tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html), you can simply use the same `tf.device` scope as in regular tensorflow:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 20, 64))
    y = LSTM(32)(x)  # all ops in the LSTM layer will live on GPU:0

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 20, 64))
    y = LSTM(32)(x)  # all ops in the LSTM layer will live on CPU:0
```

Comment: How can this be done within Keras with Tensorflow as a backend, rather than using Tensorflow to call Keras layers?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The code inside `with` can be any Keras code.

Comment: How can this be done with a trained model loaded from disk? I am currently training on gpu but want to verify afterwards on CPU

Comment: I was able to switch training from gpu to cpu in the middle of training by using the above mentioned method where I save the model in between with model.save then reload it with a different tf.device using keras.models.load_model . The same apply if you want to train then predict on a different device.

Answer (score 4):

I just spent some time figure it out.
Thoma's answer is not complete.
Say your program is `test.py`, you want to use gpu0 to run this program, and keep other gpus free.

You should write `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python test.py`

Notice it's `DEVICES` not `DEVICE`

Answer (score 1):

To disable running on the GPU (tensor flow 2.9) use `tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')`. The empty list argument is to say that there will be no GPUs visible for this run.

Do this early in your code, e.g. before Keras initializes the tf configuration.

See docs https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.9/api_docs/python/tf/config/set_visible_devices

Answer (score 0):

For people working on PyCharm, and for forcing CPU, you can add the following line in the Run/Debug configuration, under Environment variables:

```
<OTHER_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES>;CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1
```