# Limit number of cores used in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cpu-cores

I have a shared machine with 64 cores on which I have a big pipeline of Keras functions that I want to run. The thing is that it seems that Keras automatically uses all the cores available and I can't do that.

I use Python and I want to run 67 neural networks in a for loop. I would like to use half of the available cores.

I can't find any way of limiting the number of cores in Keras... Do you have any clue?

Comment: TensorFlow backend?

Comment: @Yu-Yang yes ! I use a tensorflow back end

Comment: Try adding `from keras import backend as K; K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=K.tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=32, inter_op_parallelism_threads=32)))` before running the models.

Comment: The number of cores is controlled in TensorFlow, not in Keras.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... The thing is that my keras models are in a python class. to fit the model i use a function i implemented in this class so im not sure where I am supposed to put this line ?

Comment: Normally I put it in the beginning of a file with other `import` statements.

Comment: Thank you it worked ! I just put this line before each fit I do

Comment: @Yu-Yang sorry if this is a dumb question, but don't you risk having 32 threads for intra-op and 32 for inter-op, so 64 in total ?

Comment: Good point. I think the bottleneck will be at the intra-op pool, since most of the operations in Keras are multithreaded matrix operations.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As @Yu-Yang suggested, I used these lines before each `fit`:

```py
from keras import backend as K
K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=K.tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=32,
                                                   inter_op_parallelism_threads=32)))
```

Check the CPU usage (htop) :
[image: htop example]

Comment: For information, in order to complete the answer, here you are the tf ConfigProto, containing all the options
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for inference when loading a saved model.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this solution, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54832345/5568660)

if you want to use this using Tensforflow or Tensorflow_gpu, you can directly use the tf.config and feed it to the session:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=32, 
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=32, 
                        allow_soft_placement=True)

session = tf.Session(config=config)
```