# Azure "Percentage CPU" metric on a VM

Tags: multithreading, azure, tensorflow, cpu-usage, azure-virtual-machine

What exactly is it measuring?

I have an Debian VM in Azure with **16 vCPUs**. I am using it to run tensorflow. The metric "**Percentage CPU**" on Azure Portal shows 33.5% average. My concern is that I might not fully utilize all the 16 vCPUs.

What really puzzles me is that the **`top`** command shows a dominating Python process of 600% CPU. Why is this number not consistent with Azure's 33.5%?

At one point, I was suspecting the number of tensflow threads is not enough. However, when I [increased the tensorflow threads from 5 to 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233635/tensorflow-inter-and-intra-op-parallelism-configuration), Azure "Percentage CPU" remained unchanged at 33.5%. `top -H` did show the increased number of threads though.

UPDATE:

See the accepted answer below. In the `top` screen, type `1`, it shows all the CPUs are used:

[image]

So Azure's "Percentage CPU" metric is `%CPU` you see with `top` command. Average meaning the average `%CPU` of all the CPUs.

Comment: Does this imply only 6 out of the 16 vCPUs are used?  The math is that 1 vCPU is counted by `top` as 100% CPU. So 600% shown by `top` means 6 vCPUs are used.  In the mean time, 6/16 = 37.5% which is close to Azure's 33.5% average.

Comment: In `top` screen, enter `1`, you will see single CPU usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this imply only 6 out of the 16 vCPUs are used?The math is that 1 vCPU is counted by top as 100% CPU. So 600% shown by top means 6 vCPUs are used.

No, I don't think so. 16 vCPUs are all used.

You could check this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145247/understanding-cpu-while-running-top-command).

> **%CPU**  --  CPU Usage : The percentage of your CPU that is being used by the process. **By default, `top` displays this as a percentage
>   of a single CPU.** On multi-core systems, you can have percentages
>   that are greater than 100%. For example, if 3 cores are at 60% use,
>   `top` will show a CPU use of 180%. See [here][2] for more information.
>   **You can toggle this behavior by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> while `top` is running to show the overall percentage of available
>   CPUs in use.**

You could execute `top`, then enter `1`. You will see single CPU usage.

```
top - 01:32:05 up 9 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.15, 0.38, 0.33
Tasks: 110 total,   1 running, 109 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  1.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 87.8 id, 11.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

Comment: You mean all the 16 vCPU are used such that 33.5% * 16 = 550%?  If so, why using only 33% of a single vCPU?  The entire process takes 8 hours to finish. I would like to see it using 100% CPU instead and finish in half of the time.

Comment: @neurite Yes, you could type `1` to check single CPU usage.  Single CPU usage depends on OS CPU allocation principle.

Comment: @neurite `I would like to see it using 100% CPU instead and finish in half of the time.` It also depends on your algorithm. Based on my knowledge, using multiple process could reduce running time. The right algorithm can improve CPU and memory usage and reduce runtime.

Comment: @neurite This link http://careers.directi.com/display/tu/Understanding+CPU+Utilization+and+Optimization  I think will help you understanding CPU utilization.

Comment: @neurite Hi, could you see single CPU usage?

Comment: Fine, if you have any question, you could post here.

Comment: Yeah, you right about the CPU usage. All the 16 vCPUs are used. Now the question is why it tops at 33%. But thanks a bunch for the clarification. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Per Azure support team, Azure basic metric "Percentage CPU" shows how much of the physical node the Guest OS (running your program) is actually using.   So 33% means it is actually using around 5 vCPUs fully. Note that the extended metric "CPU Percentage Guest OS" shows what the Guest OS thinks is being used when the Guest OS in running.