# Tensorflow-gpu doesn't seem to see my gpu

Tags: tensorflow, version, compatibility

I am using the TensorFlow-GPU 1.12.0 version, CUDA version 9, CUDNN version 7.0.5, bazel version 0.15 and python version 3.5.2 as mentioned in [Which TensorFlow and CUDA version combinations are compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible) for compatibility. The machine has Nvidia driver 384.130.

But the GPU of my machine is not detected by the Tensorflow by running the following command

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

the output is following as:

[

name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456

locality {}

incarnation: 13408836213255819255
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184

locality {}

incarnation: 17981738971591465658
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]

I tried the solutions in the following links

1- [Tensorflow doesn't seem to see my gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402409/tensorflow-doesnt-seem-to-see-my-gpu)

2- [list_local_device tensorflow does not detect gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871236/list-local-device-tensorflow-does-not-detect-gpu/51539914)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works in my case.

The problem with the CUDNN version in the above configuration. I update the CUDNN version to the 7.1.4 for CUDA version 9 and my code start using GPU.