# Is there R command(s) making Keras Tensorflow-GPU to run on CPU?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, gpu, cpu

I'm running Keras in R and using Tensorflow-GPU backend. Is it possible to force Keras to run on CPU without re-installing the backend?

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you 2 answers.

**Answer #1** (normal answer)

No, unfortunately not. For `keras` CPU and GPU are 2 different versions, from which you select at install time.

It seems you remember that you selected GPU at install time. I guess you're hoping that you were only setting a minor option, not selecting a version of the program. Unfortunately, you were selecting the version of `keras` to install.

**Answer #2** (ok, maybe you can "trick" `keras`)

It seems you can use environment variable values to trick `keras` into thinking that your CPU is your GPU.

This seems like it may have unexpected results, but [it seemed to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690598/can-keras-with-tensorflow-backend-be-forced-to-use-cpu-or-gpu-at-will) for these Python users.

I wouldn't worry about the fact that they are using Python. They are just using their language to set environment variables. So you can do the same in R
or directly within your OS.