# Training Keras models in two seperate juypter notebooks on CPU and GPU

Tags: python, keras, gpu, cpu

I am training Keras CNN models for two different applications on the Jupyter Notebook. Given that I want to utilize the full resources of my PC, can I use Keras-GPU in one notebook and another notebook using CPU.

I learned that Keras uses GPU by default - if available- and  I can force Keras to use CPU as 
 in [Can Keras with Tensorflow backend be forced to use CPU or GPU at will?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690598/can-keras-with-tensorflow-backend-be-forced-to-use-cpu-or-gpu-at-will). My question is that by running this line of code,

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

will the default settings change in all the running notebooks or in that particular notebook only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by running this line of code,

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

the default settings change in that particular notebook only

You can use

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ''
```

to train on CPU