# Cuda driver errors on the machine without GPU while loading model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a computer with few NVidia GPU, use packet 'segmentation_models' and build NN on the base of Unet:

```
import segmentation_models as sm
import keras.backend as K
from keras import optimizers
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model

lr = 2e-4
NUM_GPUS = 3
learning_rate = lr * NUM_GPUS

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

model = sm.Unet('efficientnetb3', encoder_weights='imagenet', classes=4, activation='softmax', encoder_freeze=False)
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=NUM_GPUS)
model = parallel_model
model.compile(adam, 'categorical_crossentropy', [dice_coef])
history = model.fit_generator(
        generator=train_gen, steps_per_epoch=len(train_gen), \
        validation_data=validation_gen, \
        epochs=50, callbacks=[clr, checkpoints, csv_logger],
        initial_epoch=0)
```

after training I save weights for future using in cpu-mode:

```
single_gpu_model = model.layers[-2]
single_gpu_model.save(single_proc_model_path_1_kernel)
```

And I try to work with theese weights:

```
import keras
model1 = keras.models.load_model(single_proc_model_path_1_kernel)
...
pr_mask = self.model1.predict(img_exp)
```

- **Machine for NN training:** Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, 3 x K80 GPU; python 3.6.7, tensorflow 1.12.0  - all code works here.
- **Win10 with 1 GeForce GTX 1080**; python 3.7.3, tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 - code works here too.
- **Win10 without NVidia GPU; tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1** - ERROR when loading model:

tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:300] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected

- **docker with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS; python 3.6.9, tensorflow 2.1.0.**
  Error when loading model:

> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
>   Segmentation Models: using `keras` framework.
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
>   I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (b36a4cf2df2e): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist

What should I change to force code to work on a machine with CPUs ony?

Comment: You need to install the tensorflow package (not tensorflow-gpu) so you only get CPU support, why are you even installing tensorflow-gpu in a machine that has no GPUs?

Comment: The last test machine (docker with ubuntu) does not have either GPU, nor tensorflow-gpu. And it does not work too.

Comment: Those warnings just say there is no GPU, it does not prevent you from using Tensorflow. Since 2.x the TF packages dynamically support both CPU and GPU

Comment: But it does not work when predicting.

Comment: You should try my suggestion of tensorflow 1.13 (not tensorflow-gpu), and also explain "does not work" in detail.

Comment: pr_mask = self.model1.predict(img_exp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1452, in predict
    if self._uses_dynamic_learning_phase():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 382, in _uses_dynamic_learning_phase
    not isinstance(K.learning_phase(), int))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 73, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: That seems to be a completely different problem, see https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13353

Comment: Thanks, I will see and answer later

Comment: I tried to use google colab first and my code works there with tensorflow 1.15, but does not work with 2.0. So, I created environment with python 3.6 and tensorflow 1.15 locally and it works here too. So, I think I have a zoo of versions of pythons and different tensorfows and it caused my problems.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 1.15 resolved all the problems. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to either blank or emptystring `""`, or possibly `-1`.

Otherwise you'll need to tell the tensorflow backend to use CPU only.

See also: [Can Keras with Tensorflow backend be forced to use CPU or GPU at will?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690598/can-keras-with-tensorflow-backend-be-forced-to-use-cpu-or-gpu-at-will)

Note that [keras multi_gpu_model is deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/multi_gpu_model) and you should alter your code to use [tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy) instead. I haven't personally worked with it but I imagine this new API is designed to work more seamlessly across GPU/CPU situations like yours.

Comment: I did not write in my post, but I used os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"