# How can I run tensorflow without GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

My system has a GPU.

When I run Tensorflow on it, TF automatically detects GPU and starts running the thread on the GPU.

How can I change this?

I.e. how can I run Tensorflow without GPU?

Comment: in terms of configuration I am not aware but you can use google colab.

Comment: Did you follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690598/can-keras-with-tensorflow-backend-be-forced-to-use-cpu-or-gpu-at-will) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work. It mainly disables the CUDA device. So, the code looks for other sources `(CPU)` to run the code.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
#os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID" #If the line below doesn't work, uncomment this line (make sure to comment the line below); it should help.
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
#Your Code Here
```